# How to find merchantId, key and slat from Payumoney

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, payumoney

I am using react native PayUMoney library

```
 initPayment(ordId) {
 let ID = this.IDganarate();

    let hashkey = HashGenerator({
    key: 'QylhKRVd',
    amount: this.state.total,
   email: "xyz@gmail.com",
    txnId: "1594976828726",
    productName: ID,
    firstName: this.state.user_data.name,
    salt: "seVTUgzrgE",
});

  console.log(hashkey);

  const payData = {
    amount: this.state.total,
    txnId: '1594976828726',
    productName: ID,
    firstName: this.state.user_data.name,
    email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    phone: this.state.pho_num,
    merchantId: '8189479',
    key: 'QylhKRVd',
    successUrl: 'https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php',
    failedUrl: 'https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php',
    isDebug: false,
    hash:hashkey,
}

Payumoney(payData).then((data) => {
    this.AddOrder(ID,ID);
}).catch((e) => {
    // Payment Failed
    console.log(e)
})
}
```

When I use testing `merchantID`, key and slat this is worked perfectly but when I use original `merchantID`, key and slat it's show me error {"code": 0, "success": false}

I think I am using wrong `merchantID`, key or slat, if you have any solution then please give me or please answer me that how can I find a right `merchantID`, key or slat